# VBA's "Like" function in MATLAB

Tags: vba, matlab

How would i turn something such as

str1 Like "?*ab*?"

into MATLAB?

Comment: What's your input and desired output? Give us some details. MATLAB support strings so you don't need to turn anything.

Comment: The question is drafted carelessly. No info given

Comment: It's a simple question, not much information is needed to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB function [contains](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) is what can be used as [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference//operators/like-operator) is used in VBA.

*Do note that* `contains` *was introduced into MATLAB 2016b.*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `contains` function does not accept wildcards like '?', or other regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at string matching with [regular expressions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) ("regexp").  Note that the regexp syntax used by Matlab differs from the one used in VBA.  In your example, the '.' takes the role of the '?' wildcard, so that you could do

```
str1 = 'aabb'; % Match
str2 = 'abab'; % No match

if isempty(regexp(str1, '.ab.'))
  disp('str1 is no match');
else
  disp('str1 is a match');
end

if isempty(regexp(str2, '.ab.'))
  disp('str2 is no match');
else
  disp('str2 is a match');
end
```

and the output you should get is

> str1 is a match
>
> str2 is no match